# Multiple Databases for Multiple Applications in Django - Can't route to the related database for a specific app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've been setting up multiple databases for multiple applications. I want my app1 application use the db_app1 database. I've done everything in the tutorials but when I try to authenticate, it doesn't route to db_app1 database in the settings file, instead it routes to the default database. I need to use the db_app1 database for the app1 application. What am I missing?

This is my dbRouter.py file:

```
class App1DbRouter(object):

    route_app_labels = ['app1']

    """
    A router to control app1 app db operations
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        """
        Attempts to read app1 models go to db_app1.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'db_app1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        """
        Attempts to read app1 models go to db_app1.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'db_app1'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        """
                Allow relations if a model in the app1 app is
                involved.
        """
        if (
                obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
                obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'db_app1'
        return None
```

My settings.py file

```
....
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
]
....
....
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db_app1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': 'my_host',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.dbRouter.App1DbRouter',]
```

Comment: can you tell how exactly are you trying to authenticate? a spesific view or admin interface? if so can you share that part too?

Comment: @engin_ipek I am using social authentication (Google login) and it is working but using the default database. It seems, routing is app_label driven, and it doesn't get it right. But don't know why.

Comment: Add social_django to route_app_labels

Comment: When I add the social_django to the route_app_labels, I get this error: 'AttributeError at /oauth/complete/google-oauth2/',  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

Comment: Okay, it worked when I added both social_django and auth application to the route_app_labels.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked when I added social_django and auth application to the route_app_labels.

```
route_app_labels = ['mammothholdings','social_django','auth']
```

Thanks @engin_ipek for inspiring me for the solution.